# Spark split a column value into multiple rows

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

My problem is I have a table like this:

```
------------------------
A  B    C
------------------------
a1 b2   c1|c2|c3|c4
```

c1|c2|c3|c4 is one value separated by |.

My final result should look like this:

```
---------
A  B   C
---------
a1 b1  c1
a1 b1  c2
a1 b1  c3
a1 b1  c4
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you could do, [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#split-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) the string with pipe and [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#split-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) the data using spark function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(("a1", "b1", "c1|c2|c3|c4")).toDF("A", "B", "C")

df.withColumn("C", explode(split($"C", "\\|"))).show
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1|
| a1| b1| c2|
| a1| b1| c3|
| a1| b1| c4|
+---+---+---+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I figured it out, it should be "\\|" :) everything else is perfect, thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot you found it I was trying to  update too

Comment: Hi just one more question. If I have multiple columns like this, how do I explode them together?

Comment: You can add withcolumn for other multiple columns