# Spark SQL row splitting on string delimiter

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-analysis-services

I'm looking for a way to split some rows from a table based on a string field exactly like the problem from this post:
[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)
[Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

The issue is I can only use Queries, and Spark SQL doesn't seem to support recursive CTEs or Cross Apply so all the answers that previous post won't work in this case.

I Tried using the methods that I would use in SQL server (cross apply or recursive CTEs) but i'm not sure if Spark SQL has any way to do this without those methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark split a column value into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171570/spark-split-a-column-value-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: and here is more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912153/how-to-split-single-row-into-multiple-rows-in-spark-dataframe-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Without the ability to use recursive **CTE**s or cross apply, splitting rows based on a string field in Spark SQL becomes more difficult.

The **explode** function in Spark SQL can be used to split an array or map column into multiple rows.
While it do not work directly with strings, you will have to  first split the string column into an array using the split function and then apply the explode function to the resulting array column.

Using the **posexplode** function
Similar to explode, the posexplode function can be used to split an array or map column into multiple rows, but it also includes the position of each value in the array.
This function can be used to split a string column by treating it as an array of characters.

For example I have created a data frame and a SQL table I have provided both the approaches
[image]

[image]
[image]
You have 2 approaches
**Using the explode function:
Using the posexplode function:**

The above both approaches will work in SQL and Pyspark.

**Explode Function:**

```
%sql
-- split string column using explode function
SELECT id, exploded_value
FROM fruits_table
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(fruits, ',')) exploded_table AS exploded_value;
```

[image]
[image]
**posexplode function:**

```
%sql
-- split string column using posexplode function
SELECT id, pos, substr(fruits, pos, 1) AS exploded_value
FROM fruits_table
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(split(fruits, '')) exploded_table AS pos, val;
```

[image]

In Pyspark you will have to import the functions like below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, posexplode
```

[image]

- **split the fruits string into an array of strings**
- **Using a new column as fruits_arr**
- `fruits_df = fruits_df.withColumn("fruits_arr", split("fruits", ","))`

[image]

[image]
use posexplode to explode the fruits_arr and generate a position column

```
fruits_df = fruits_df.selectExpr("id", "posexplode(fruits_arr) as (pos, fruit)")
```

[image]